# How can I find all elements from a specified XPATH but accept slightly variable IDs with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

So I'm trying to get ALL elements EXACTLY like this with the exception that the numbers after ccid can be anything

```
//*[@id="ccid_4587719"]/td[12]/text()[1]
```

This code below gets elements almost to my liking but it also pulls up two extra elements and I'm not sure how to code it to get only the one shown above (with the exception i talked about):

```
classnames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "ccid")]/td[12]')
```

The code above (classnames variable) is almost perfect but I don't want it to pull these elements:

```
//*[@id="ccid_4587719"]/td[12]/a[2]
//*[@id="ccid_4587719"]/td[12]/text()[3]
```

Basically, I want the first element under each ID.
If you need clarification, please tell me. I will do my best to explain.

Comment: Could you clarify what elements you want and which ones you don't want. It's not completely clear to me.

Comment: You have to use " and not " to join ones you don't need.

Comment: Add html in text format or share the url so we can understand and help you

Comment: I can't share the link as contains personal information, unfortunately.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bZ6hsRZL

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: @VihaanDutta Website is not accessible, but what about this: `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "ccid")]/child::td[12]')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have almost correct xpath, where you just need to indicate that you need only first occurense of element?

```
   //*[startsWith(@id, 'ccid_')]/td[12]/text()[1]
```

You can also try one of these ones, if it suites you:

```
   //*[startsWith(@id, 'ccid_')]/td[12]/*[1]/text()
   //*[startsWith(@id, 'ccid_')]/td[12]//text()[1]
```

To give you precise answer, we need to see html structure of td[12]